# How to use OR operator with command FINDSTR from a Windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, findstr

`Findstr` is supposed to support regular expressions and the way I am using it I need to have an **OR** to check if a file ends in `.exe` **OR** `.dll`. However I cannot get the **OR** operation to work. Windows thinks on using `|` that I try to pipe the previous command and `OR` is read as literal **OR**.

Comment: `findstr` uses whitespace to delimit `OR` matched search patterns, e.g. `findstr /ri "\.exe$ \.dll$"`. If the pattern itself has whitespace, you can specify multiple `/c` patterns, e.g. `findstr /ri /c:" .*\.exe$" /c:" .*\.dll$"`.

Answer (score 11):

`findstr.exe` in Windows system32 directory supports only a very limited set of regular expression characters. Running in a command prompt window `findstr /?` results in getting displayed help for this console application listing also the supported regular expression characters with their meanings.

But as **Eryk Sun** explained in his comment above, multiple search strings can be specified on command line to build a simple **OR** expression.

In case of having a list file `FileNames.lst` containing for example

```
C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll
C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe.mui
```

and just all file names ending with `.dll` **OR** `.exe` case-insensitive should be output by command **findstr**, the command line for getting this output could be:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\findstr.exe /I /R "\.exe$ \.dll$" FileNames.lst
```

The output is for the example lines in `FileNames.lst`:

```
C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll
C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
```

The space in regular expression search string is interpreted by **findstr** as a separator between the two strings. Therefore **findstr** searches with the regular expression strings `\.dll$` and `\.exe$` and returns all lines where one of the two expressions matches a string.

Another method to **OR** two or more regular expression strings would be using parameter `/C:"..."` multiple times on command line which is necessary when a regular expression search string contains one or more spaces which should be included as literal character(s) in search expression.

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\findstr.exe /I /R /C:"\.dll$" /C:"\.exe$" FileNames.lst
```

The result is the same as above with the other command line.

But for this specific task it is not necessary at all to run a regular expression search as **findstr** offers also the parameter `/E` for returning only lines where the searched strings are found at end of a line.

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\findstr.exe /E /I /C:.exe /C:.dll FileNames.lst
```

A brief description between the differences on using `"..."` or `/C:"..."`:

1. `"regexp1 regexp2 regexp3"` means searching for a line with a string matched by one of the three space separated regular expressions. The option `/R` can be used additionally to explicitly interpret the three strings between the two spaces as regular expressions. It is advisable to do so for making it 100% clear for `findstr` and every reader that the search strings are interpreted as regular expressions.
2. `/L "word1 word2 word3"` means searching for a line with a string matched by one of the three space separated literally interpreted strings. The used option `/L` forces explicitly an interpretation of the three strings between the two spaces as literal strings and not as regular expressions.
3. `/C:"word 1" /C:"word 2" /C:"word 3"` means searching for a line with a string matched by one of the three literally interpreted strings on which the space character is interpreted as space. The option `/L` can be used additionally to explicitly interpret the three search strings between as literal strings. It is advisable to do so for making it 100% clear for `findstr` and every reader that the search strings are interpreted as literal strings.
4. `/R /C:"reg exp 1" /C:"reg exp 2" /C:"reg exp 3"` means searching for a line with a string matched by one of the three regular expressions strings on which the space character is interpreted as space. The option `/R` forces explicitly an interpretation of the three strings as regular expressions with space being interpreted as space.