# FINDSTR skips command output if returning false

Tags: batch-file

I just want to understand how `FINDSTR` works. For example I have the following (test) batch script:

```
set someText=hi
echo %sometext% | findstr /i /c:"hello"
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo PASSED
) else (
echo NOT PASSED
)
pause
```

In this example, if `someText` contains "hello", for example "Hello, world!", the output would be:

```
Hello, world!
PASSED
```

But if `someText` does not contain "hello", it will simply output:

```
NOT PASSED
```

Why? Where did my `echo %someText%` go? And how to bring it back?

Comment: the ouput of `echo` is filtered by `findstr`. It does only display matching strings.

Comment: The question is answered by the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)). The output of __ECHO__ to handle __STDOUT__ (standard output) of `cmd` is redirected by `cmd` to handle __STDIN__ (standard input) of the executable `%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe` run by `cmd` after command __ECHO__ by calling the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw).

Comment: The space left to `|` is also output by the `cmd` internal command __ECHO__ because of __ECHO__ does not interpret a space as argument string delimiter as most [Windows commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) do. __CD__ is another command which does not interpret a space as argument string delimiter. IT would be necessary using `echo %sometext%| findstr /i /c:"hello"` for avoiding the output of a trailing space which would be important on using `set someText=hi` and `echo %sometext%| findstr /i /x /c:"hi"`; note option `/x`.

Comment: `echo %sometext% | findstr /i /x /c:"hi"` would not result in a positive match as the entire line is not matched by the search string `hi` because of the trailing space output by `echo` too.

Comment: `if %errorlevel%==0 (` should be `if not errorlevel 1` as described by the help output on running `if /?` in a command prompt window because of this syntax works always even within a command block beginning with `(` and ending with matching `)`. There could be used also `echo %sometext%| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /i /c:"hello" && echo FOUND|| echo NOT FOUND`. See also: [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564).

Comment: If there is left to the redirection operator `|` specified the execution of another executable, everything output by this executable to standard output is redirected by `cmd` to standard input of `findstr`. If a command block beginning with `(` and ending with a matching `)` is used left to the redirection operator `|`, the output to standard output of all commands executables is redirected to standard input of `findstr`. Example: `(call /? & for /?) | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /C:~ /C:CALL /C:FOR` That command line redirects the help of __CALL__ and __FOR__ to __FINDSTR__.

Comment: __FINDSTR__ searches __case-sensitive__ and __literally__ in all lines on standard input for `~` __OR__ `CALL` __OR__ `FOR` and outputs each line containing one of these three strings. See also: [How to use OR operator with command FINDSTR from a Windows command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32159911/3074564) There is run first by `cmd.exe` the executable `findstr.exe` and then is run the internal command __CALL__ with argument `/?` and the internal command __FOR__ with the argument `/?` of which output is redirected to input of __FINDSTR__ which then terminates.

Comment: There can be used the free Windows Sysinternals (Microsoft) tool [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see what is going on in background. Download the ZIP file of this tool, extract it to a local directory, run *Process Monitor* with standard filter settings and run next in a command prompt window: `(ping 127.0.0.1 & tracert 127.0.0.1) | findstr /C:127.0.0.1` There can be seen in log of *Process Monitor* how `cmd.exe` first starts `findstr.exe`, next `ping.exe`, then `tracert.exe` and finally `finstr.exe` terminates and `cmd.exe` remains.

Comment: How does `findstr.exe` know that there will be no more input to search for the string? `cmd.exe` writes to standard input of `findstr.exe` the [end of file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) control character (most likely or the [end of transmission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Transmission_character) as never debugged by me) after the execution of the last command/executable finished which signals `findstr.exe` the end of the data stream. `findstr.exe` closes itself now and the execution of the entire command line with three executables is finished now.

Answer (score 1):

The `"|"` in your command passed standard output from the `echo` command to the standard input of the `findstr` command.

The output "Hello, world!" seen when matched is the standard output from the `findtr` command when matched. It is not the output from the `echo` command

Comment: is there any way to execute the `echo` command or whatever command is before `findstr` first, then pass the output to `findstr`?

Comment: @ItsSuperPlayz: Just execute `echo %sometext%` alone _before_ the line with the `findstr`...

Answer (score 1):

`findstr` filters your text (shows matching lines and suppresses non-matching lines). Nothing you can do about that, so you need another approach. Redirect the `findstr` output to `NUL` ("nirwana") so you have a consistent behaviour with matches and non-matches. Then echo the string again:

```
set someText=hi
echo %sometext% | findstr /i /c:"hello" >nul
echo %sometext%
if %errorlevel%==0 (
  echo PASSED
) else (
  echo NOT PASSED
)
pause
```