# Invalid syntax using findstr

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am using below batch script to create user in the system. This script is being called by another script based on the request like if the request is create, it triggers this script and if it is modify, it triggers modify script.

Scripts when called through main script is working fine but if the below script is run manaully, i am getting the syntax of the command is incorrect

I am getting the error at `IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0`

```
CD E:\Batches\User_Process\Report
CALL Update_Report.bat
CD E:\Batches\User_Process\Create\HSS_Groups
CALL Export_Group_Batch.bat
FINDSTR /m "no rows selected" "E:\Batches\User_Process\Create\HSS_Groups\V_C_REQUEST_2.csv"
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
  ECHO "user is not created"
  CD E:\Batches\User_Process\Create\Create_User
  CALL Export_Create_Users.bat
)
FINDSTR /m "no rows selected" "E:\Batches\User_Process\Create\HSS_Groups\V_C_REQUEST_2.csv"
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==1 (
  ECHO "user is already created"
)
```

**[EDIT /]**

Removed surrounding `"`'s from `IF` as it was not there in the script.

Comment: The `if` **syntax** is fine. Bit it's **logic**  isn't. You compare `0` with `"0"`, which will never be true. Remove the quotes or quote *both* sides of the comparison.

Comment: Also, your `findstr` finds every line that contains `no` *or*  `rows` *or* `selected` (and even worse, things like `another` (because of the contained `no`). Use `find` instead or use findstr's `/c` switch.

Comment: @Stephan I dont have "" in if condition.. I have tried with Find /c and getting the same issue

Comment: Please always cut-and-paste code. I suspect that you have omitted the required space after the `0` in the suspect line. The result of `find` or `findstr /c:"no rows selected"` is `errorlevel 0` if the string *is* found. There appears to be no purpose in the `/m` switch. Note that *if* the result of the `find...` command, whichever is used, is `0` then the associated block is run and **then** the second `if` condition will be applied to the resultant `errorlevel` of the `CALL Export_Create_Users.bat` command.

Comment: @Magoo I don't have access to copy the code but it is exactly as it is. If i break the code and keep the below script in a test.bat and execute it, it is not giving me any error but in the script i get syntax error

FINDSTR /m "no rows selected" "E:\Batches\User_Process\Create\HSS_Groups\V_C_REQUEST_2.csv"
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
  ECHO "user is not created")

Comment: Please open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/), run `if /?` and read at least the first output usage help for the command __IF__. The correct syntax to use for checking exit code of a previous executed command or executable is `IF [NOT] ERRORLEVEL number command`. See also [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an alternate syntax using the conditional command operators `&&` and `||`.

Comment: My answer on [symbol equivalent to NEQ, LSS, GTR, etc. in Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386323/3074564) describes in full details how a string comparison is done by the command __IF__ which is always done on one of the two compared strings is enclosed in `"`. Next read: [How to use OR operator with command FINDSTR from a Windows command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32159911/3074564) It explains the difference between `"word1 word2 word3"` and `/C:"word1 word2 word3"` as  search string for __FINDSTR__ which is with full file name `%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe`.

Comment: The command __ECHO__ does not interpret `"` as beginning/end of an argument strings like most of the [Windows commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands). __ECHO__ interprets `"` literally. I doubt that you really want to output `user is not created` and `user is already created` enclosed in `"` as there is no reason to do so. See also [debugging a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564).

Comment: Upvoting this. This is a -very- common problem for developers. It has probably been duplicated -many- times.