# How to list several items in the dialog box for execution?

Tags: windows, for-loop, if-statement, batch-file, goto

How can I use a defined menu type list for running a range of selections, i.e. conditionally tick off the selected items at once.

Conventionally, the configurator looks like this:

```bash
@echo off
chcp 1251 >nul
:begin
echo  [1] Folder 1  [3] Folder 3
echo  [2] Folder 2  [4] Folder 4
set /P op=Enter the number: 
if "%op%"=="1" goto op1
if "%op%"=="2" goto op2
if "%op%"=="3" goto op3
if "%op%"=="4" goto op4
:op1
cls
call "Delete_Folder1.bat" >nul
echo Done
timeout /t 2 >nul
cls
goto begin
:op2
cls
call "Delete_Folder2.bat" >nul
echo Done
timeout /t 2 >nul
goto begin
:op3
cls
call "Delete_Folder3.bat" >nul
echo Done
timeout /t 2 >nul
cls
goto begin
:op4
cls
call "Delete_Folder4.bat" >nul
echo Done
timeout /t 2 >nul
cls
goto begin
```

I don't understand how to select multiple items at once. Conditionally 1 and 3, or 2, 3 and 4, That is, to list several items in a row, and have them all fulfilled.

Comment: You would need four separate input variables to capture all the choices. You could then set up a loop that tests each one in turn and calls the appropriate script or not, depending on the settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution would be using a fail-safe and secure single choice solution with the [Windows command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) **CHOICE**.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com') do for %%H in (%%G) do set /A "CodePage=%%H" 2>nul
%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com 1251 1>nul

:Begin
cls
echo  [1] Folder 1  [3] Folder 3
echo  [2] Folder 2  [4] Folder 4
echo  [E] Exit
echo(
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 1234E /N /M "Enter the number or E for exit:"
if errorlevel 5 goto EndBatch
if not errorlevel 1 goto Begin
echo(
call "%~dp0Delete_Folder%ERRORLEVEL%.bat" 1>nul
echo Done
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 2 1>nul
goto Begin

:EndBatch
%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com %CodePage% 1>nul
cls
endlocal
```

A more difficult solution is a multiple choice solution using `set /P`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com') do for %%H in (%%G) do set /A "CodePage=%%H" 2>nul
%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com 1251 1>nul

:Begin
cls
echo  [1] Folder 1  [3] Folder 3
echo  [2] Folder 2  [4] Folder 4
echo(
set "UserChoice="
set /P "UserChoice=Enter one or more space or comma separated numbers: " || goto Begin
set "UserChoice=%UserChoice:"=%"
if not defined UserChoice goto Begin
echo "%UserChoice%"| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /C:"^\"[1234][ ,1234]*\"$" 1>nul || goto Begin

for %%I in (%UserChoice%) do if %%I GEQ 1 if %%I LEQ 4 call "%~dp0Delete_Folder%%I.bat" 1>nul
echo Done

%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 2 1>nul
%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com %CodePage% 1>nul
cls
endlocal
```

A prompt of the user for input with `set /P` gives a user the freedom to enter anything from an empty string to an intentionally completely wrong string or a by mistake typed wrong string.

See: [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564) This answer describes very detailed both techniques used in the two batch files above.

The following command line in second batch file needs some extra explanation:

```
echo "%UserChoice%"| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /C:"^\"[1234][ ,1234]*\"$" 1>nul || goto Begin
```

It is necessary to reference the value of the environment variable `UserChoice` enclosed in `"` for getting all characters of user input string interpreted literally including characters like `&<>|` being otherwise interpreted as operators before the string is output with command `echo` which outputs also the two double quotes. See: [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)

The user input string enclosed in `"` is redirected as input to `findstr` which runs a case-sensitive regular expression search with interpreting the space character as literal character because of using the options `/R` and `/C:`. The regular expression search is positive only on the input string

1. begins with `"` as written in the batch file,
2. has next a digit in range 1 to 4,
3. has optionally more spaces, commas or digits in range 1 to 4,
4. and ends with `"` as written in the batch file.

There is used `1234` and not `1-4` in the two square brackets as the latter would result in matching also `¹²³` which is not acceptable in this case.

It is important here that no space is left to the redirection operator `|` because of `echo` would also output that space and `findstr` would never find a positive match with the specified expression on trailing space output by `echo`.

The input validation done with `findstr` results in an exit with value `1` meaning no match if the user enters a string like `1, 6, 08` or `1, <batch> & test, 2` in which case the user is prompted once again.

But an input like `1,3 4, 2 11,, ,32 4321 444444444444444444444` results in a positive find with exit code `0` and the **FOR** loop is run next with calling:

```
"%~dp0Delete_Folder1.bat"
"%~dp0Delete_Folder3.bat"
"%~dp0Delete_Folder4.bat"
"%~dp0Delete_Folder2.bat"
```

The numbers `11`, `32`, `4321`, `444444444444444444444` are ignored because of the two **IF** conditions.

The second batch file does not prompt the user a second time because the user has the freedom to enter all four numbers at once on prompt.

Both batch files determine the current code page before changing it to [Windows-1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) and restore that code page before exiting. That is recommended for any batch file which changes the default code page in case of the user runs the batch file from within a command prompt window instead of double clicking on it in *Windows File Explorer* and the user continues using the command prompt with expecting usage of default code page after batch file execution finished. See [Saving current codepage](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8533#p56647) on *DosTips* for more details.

See also:

- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564)
- [How to use OR operator with command FINDSTR from a Windows command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32159911/3074564)
- DosTips forum topic: [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774)

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?`
- `chcp /?`
- `choice /?`
- `cls /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `timeout /?`

Comment: Your answer, which will take me a long time to study, has already helped me a lot, thank you. However, I still have some questions:
— What is the difference between the Choice and UserChoice commands?
— What does the set "UserChoice=" command do if the variable is not set?
— I do not understand why the characters (",%,=) in the line set "UserChoice=%UserChoice:"=%" are located exactly like this.
— The command echo "%UserChoice%" should not output the text of the variable, or does it serve a different purpose?

Comment: @Amateur_Play All your questions should be answered on the referenced web pages. [choice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/choice) is a Windows command which in this case is an executable installed with Windows in the `System32` directory since Windows Vista and Windows Server 2003. It is extra designed for a single choice prompt in a batch file. `UserChoice` is an environment variable with the string `UserChoice` as name. You can use also any other name for this environment variable as long as not using the name of a  predefined variable.

Comment: `set "UserChoice="` just makes sure that the environment variable `UserChoice` is undefined in the local environment. Any environment variable used in a batch file can be defined already outside of the batch file if a user opens a command prompt window and defines the environment variable there or runs a batch file multiple times from within the command prompt window instead of double clicking the batch file for [debugging a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564) and for testing it.

Comment: It is good coding practice to make sure that an environment variable is definitely undefined which should be undefined on execution of a batch file. As the referenced answer on [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564) explains, if an environment variable is already defined perhaps in the environment defined outside of the batch file and the user hits just __RETURN__ or __ENTER__ on prompt with `set /P`, the environment variable keeps its current value on being already defined.

Comment: That should be avoid here. The batch file is designed for deleting entire folders. It should never happen that folders are deleted by chance just because of `UserChoice` is defined somehow outside of the batch file and the user hits by mistake __RETURN__ or __ENTER__ before entering at least one number. Experienced programmers call that a __secure__ code design. Something done before batch file execution cannot cause the deletion of one or more folders on user of the batch file does not explicitly enter at least one number.

Comment: `set "UserChoice=%UserChoice:"=%"` is also explained in full details in the answer on [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564) That is a command line for a __fail-safe__ AND __secure__ usage of the batch file. What does __fail-safe__ mean here? Let us assume the user uses a German keyboard and presses quickly the key __2__ above the letters __Q__ and __W__ and next __RETURN__ to enter `2`.

Comment: But there is currently __Caps Lock__ enabled (and `German IBM` keyboard layout is not used) resulting in entering `"` instead of `2`. This line removes from the user input string all `"` by replacing each double quote character in the user input string currently assigned to the environment variable with name `UserChoice` with an empty string and redefines the environment variable `UserChoice` with the remaining string. In this case with just `"` entered and nothing else, the command line expands to `set "UserChoice="` resulting in `UserChoice` environment variable becomes undefined again.

Comment: Any `"` input by the user of the batch file by mistake or intentionally on trying to find a security leakage for doing something completely different than written in the batch file not removed before further usage of `%UserProfile%` would cause either a syntax error with an immediate exit of batch file processing or doing something completely different as the batch file is written for. I think you can imagine how astonished a user would be on __quickly__ typing __by mistake__ `"` and __RETURN__ and the console window closes because of `cmd.exe` exits batch processing caused by a syntax error.

Comment: `set "UserChoice=%UserChoice:"=%"` makes sure that the user input string assigned to the environment variable `UserChoice` is always without any `"`. That guarantees now that all other command lines in the batch file below this command line are executed as really written in the batch file and never cause a syntax error or doing something completely different. In other words the batch file is __fail-safe__ even on by mistake wrong user input and __secure__ if a user tries to hijack the batch file for malicious purposes on being for example stored on a server with lots of data files.

Answer (score 1):

processing a list is quite easy with a `for`loop:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set /P "op=Enter the number(s, separated by space or comma): "
echo DEBUG: %op%
for %%i in (%op%) do call :op%%i 2>nul|| goto :fail
goto :eof

:op1
echo one
goto :eof

:op2
echo two
goto :eof

:op3
echo three
goto :eof

:op4
echo four
goto :eof

:fail
echo wrong input
goto :of
```

some more verifying for correct input might be desirable.